# Escaping + in Salesforce REST QUERY

Tags: rest-api, query

I'm trying to escape test+test@test.com email in salesforce REST query.

https://na16.salesforce.com/services/data/v32.0/query/?q=SELECT+Id+FROM+Contact+WHERE+Email='test+test@test.com'

But it replaces + sign with space, before parsing a query. That results in error:

> { message: " Id FROM Contact WHERE Email LIKE 'test\ test@test.com' ^
>   ERROR at Row:1:Column:40 Invalid string literal 'test\ test@test.com'.
>   Illegal character sequence '\ ' in string literal." errorCode:
>   "MALFORMED_QUERY" }

Is it possible to escape + on url, so it's treated correctly when query parsed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the most elegant solution but I've encountered the same problem before, you're more than welcome to use this:

```
    strQuery = 'YOUR+QUERY+HERE';
    strQuery = strEndPoint.replace('%','%25');
    strQuery = strEndPoint.replace(' ','%20');
    strQuery = strEndPoint.replace('+','%2B');
    strQuery = strEndPoint.replace('\'','%27');
```

then add more escape character replacements as necessary depending on the characters you're using in your querystring.

After all that, just append strQuery to 'https://na16.salesforce.com/services/data/v32.0/query/?q='.

Comment: https://na16.salesforce.com/services/data/v32.0/query/?q=SELECT+Id+FROM+Contact+WHERE+Email='test%2Btest@test.com'
Have worked out

Answer (score 10):

[EncodingUtil.urlEncode()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_encodingUtil.htm#apex_System_EncodingUtil_urlEncode) will do what you are looking for:

```
String stringToEncode = 'test+test@test.com';
String encodedUrl = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(stringToEncode, 'UTF-8');
System.debug(encodedUrl);
```

The code above outputs:

> test%2Btest%40test.com

You can use `EncodingUtil.urlDecode()` to get it back to its original form.

Comment: This. So much this. The correct tool for the job.